# Getting dictionary for each feature with their attribute values using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, features, dictionary

I need to obtain, for each feature of a layer, a dictionary with the attribute names and their values using PyQGIS.

I can get all the attributes of the layer using:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

indiv = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Individuos')[0]

for feature in features:
    value = feature[field.name()]
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    print(attrs)
```

But what I need is to create a dictionary with field names as key and their value for each feature.

Comment: There's a bit of code between `indiv=` and `for feature in features:` that you've not shown. One line to get `features` from the layer and another to get `field`, or better still all the field names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`QgsJsonUtils`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsJsonUtils.html) class has [`exportAttributes`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsJsonUtils.html#a25746cf96b0327f3dc587ee385e3aa95) method for getting attributes as a `dict`.

**Solution 1**:

Making a dictionary including feature `"id"` as key, attributes map as value:

```
{feature1.id: {attr1: value, attr2: value, ...},
 feature2.id: {attr1: value, attr2: value, ...},
 ...}
```

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LAYER_NAME')[0]

features_dict = {f.id(): QgsJsonUtils.exportAttributes(f) for f in layer.getFeatures()}
```

**Solution 2**:

Making a list including attributes map (`dict`) of features:

```
[{attr1: value, attr2: value, ...}, # feature 1
 {attr1: value, attr2: value, ...}, # feature 2
 ...]
```

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LAYER_NAME')[0]

features_list = [QgsJsonUtils.exportAttributes(f) for f in layer.getFeatures()]
```

Comment: Your solution 1 is perfect for what I'm looking. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 11):

The snippet below should help you. It just prints a dictionary for each feature to the console, but you could do something else with the feature attribute dictionaries if you wanted.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

def print_atts_dict(layer, feature):
    flds = [f for f in layer.fields()]
    atts = {}
    for f in flds:
        atts[f.name()] = feature[f.name()]
    print(atts)
    
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print_atts_dict(layer, f)
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
# get the fields and features:
fields = indiv.fields()
features = indiv.getFeatures()

# initialise an empty dict with each field name:
attdict = {}
for field in fields:
    attdict[field.name()] = []

# for each field in each feature, append the relevant field data to the dict item:
for feature in features:
  for field in fields:
    v = feature[field.name()]
    attdict[field.name()].append(v)

print(attdict)
```

That gives a `dict` that looks like this for some Ghana regions:

```
{'shapeName': ['Greater Accra', 'Central', 'Western', 'Eastern', 'Ashanti', 'Volta', 'Brong Ahafo', 'Northern', 'Upper West', 'Upper East'],
 'shapeISO': ['GH-AA', 'GH-CP', 'GH-WP', 'GH-EP', 'GH-AH', 'GH-TV', 'GH-BA', 'GH-NP', 'GH-UW', 'GH-UE'],
 'shapeID': ['GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B1', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B2', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B3', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B4', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B5', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B6', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B7', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B8', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B9', 'GHA-ADM1-1590546715-B10'],
 'shapeGroup': ['GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA', 'GHA'], 'shapeType': ['ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1', 'ADM1']}
```

Which I *think* is what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is using the underdog `__geo_interface__`, that was defined by Sean Gillies at https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
    
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    attributes = feature.__geo_interface__["properties"]
    print(attributes)
```

---

**References:**

- [Adding `__geo_interface__` to QGIS geometry and feature](https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/adding-__geo_interface__-to-qgis-geometry-and-feature/)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution utilizes the [`attributeMap()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#ae8c272f7ccca1b3cd40b8ec021218c70) method of the [`QgsFeature`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html) class.

> Returns the feature's attributes as a map of the field name to value.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attributes = feat.attributeMap()
    attributes_ = {key : value if not isinstance(value, QDate) else value.toString("dd.MM.yyyy") for key, value in attributes.items()}
    print(feat.id(), attributes_)
```

That results into:

```
0 {'ColumnA': '1, Michigan Street, Michigan', 'ColumnB': 'Michigan Street', 'ColumnC': '01.05.2023', 'id': 1, 'integer': NULL, 'real': 15.15, 'string': 'Some Text', 'trouble': 'a'}
1 {'ColumnA': NULL, 'ColumnB': NULL, 'ColumnC': '30.04.2023', 'id': 2, 'integer': 100, 'real': NULL, 'string': 'Some Text', 'trouble': 'b'}
2 {'ColumnA': NULL, 'ColumnB': NULL, 'ColumnC': '02.05.2023', 'id': 3, 'integer': 100, 'real': 5.25, 'string': NULL, 'trouble': 'c'}
3 {'ColumnA': NULL, 'ColumnB': NULL, 'ColumnC': NULL, 'id': 4, 'integer': NULL, 'real': NULL, 'string': NULL, 'trouble': 'd'}
4 {'ColumnA': NULL, 'ColumnB': NULL, 'ColumnC': '03.05.2023', 'id': 5, 'integer': NULL, 'real': 10.1, 'string': 'Some Text', 'trouble': 'e'}
```

*Note:* There was performed one more additional step due to the type of an attribute - [`QDate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdate.html) class which will appear as `PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2023, 5, 3)` when one simply applies the `feat.attributeMap()`.